# Intent send MenuItem or any object to the launching activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to pass the clicked `menu item` through `intent` to the launching activity and there I want to disable this item until the activity is active but the app crashes if I try to do this with parceable or serializable. 
Here is my code.

```
Intent postActivity = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, PostActivity.class);
     postActivity.putExtra("Menu Item", (Parcelable) menuItem);
     startActivity(postActivity);
```

In the being launched activity.

```
MenuItem item = (MenuItem) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Menu Item");
item.setEnabled(false);
```

I googled it but didn't find a solution. I also tried myself but not working.
If you guys can help me. Thanks so much.

Comment: You cannot pass a `MenuItem` between activities. Each activity is responsible for its own action bar/toolbar contents.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. The launching activity extends the activating activity. What is the simplest way to get this job done? Thanks.

Comment: "What is the simplest way to get this job done?" -- what is "this job"? From what I can see, you would just simply disable the `MenuItem` before calling `startActivity()`. Or, worry about it in `onStart()` when it is coming back to the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

If your launched activity is extending launching activity(as you are saying)
In your launching activity do this

```
public Menu menu;
```

then in your on onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
this.menu = menu;
```

Then in your launched activity's onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_item_id);
item.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: I don't want to override the `onCreateOptoinMenu()` method in the extended activity. Anyhow thanks for your reply..